# gsutil cp: "Too many resumable upload attempts failed without progress."

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, cp, gsutil

I'm running gsutil cp on a Compute Engine to transfer 1.5TB of files (2-150MB each) from S3 to GCS. I'm finding that copying chokes with multiple "Too many resumable upload attempts failed without progress. You might try this upload again later." (ABORT_CUR_PROCESS) errors. The .gsutil directory starts filling up with failed transfers. This does not happen consistently, though it often happens when transferring first starts. After a while gsutil aborts.

The command line I'm using is:

```
gsutil cp -c -L ~/S3.log -R s3://<bucket>/<folder> gs://<bucket>/ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I initially tried with '-m' but, seeing error messages, I then tried running it without '-m'. I've also tried running two parallel transfers between different folders, logging to different log files.

I'm using an f1-micro, which may be inadequate, but I would like confirmation of that before I try setting up a new instance. CPU usage is around 50% and swap file size is 0k, so it doesn't look to me like the problem is insufficient CPU or memory resource. Network traffic is about 1MBytes/s in and out, which is unexpectedly slow but, as far as I can tell, available bandwidth is the same for all Compute Engine instances. Incidentally, the CE and CS are both in the US-Central region, but the S3 bucket is in Ireland.

Any insights you can share?

Comment: I went ahead and created an n1-highcpu-2 CE and gsutil runs much more happily, so clearly an f1-micro is underpowered for the task.